# Python (Bokeh) : How do i plot a line graph by using my CSV values and converting them to my outcome?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a CSV File with columns below:
Time Format being Month/Date/Year Hour:Minutes

| Time | Event | Speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/30/2022 17:23 | Speeding | 50 |
| 1/28/2022 18:22 | Speeding | 20 |
| 1/27/2022 22:00 | Speeding | 30 |
| 1/26/2022 23:23 | Speeding | 40 |
| 1/27/2022 22:00 | Stopping | 10 |
| 1/26/2022 23:23 | Stopping | 10 |

-With the new codes my graph, will show the dates below, however i am trying to have it plot against the hours instead. This is because i am trying to show the correlation between the speed within a day to see which period of the day have higher speed.

**New Codes**:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool

output_file('Speed.html')  # output for average speed graph

file = 'C:/Users/oof/Desktop/route.csv'  # read csv file
df = pd.read_csv(file)  # import data to pandas dataframe

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').dt.time
grouped_by_time = df.groupby('Time')[['Speed']].mean()
print(grouped_by_time)

source = ColumnDataSource(grouped_by_time)
p1 = figure(x_axis_type='datetime')
p1.line(x='Time', y='Speed', line_width=2, source=source)
p1.title.text = 'Average Speed in a Day'
p1.yaxis.axis_label = 'Average Speed'
p1.xaxis.axis_label = '24-Hour'
TOOLTIP1 = [("Time", "@Time{%H:%M}"),
            ("Average Speed: ", "@Speed")]
p1.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=TOOLTIP1, formatters={"@Time": "datetime"}, mode='vline'))

show(p1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and Welcome on SO @WJstudent,

you can convert date values to a datetime object with pandas using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime#pandas.to_datetime).

To group only by `time` and not by `datetime`, I dropped the date information and keept the time unsing `pd.Timedstamp.dt.time`.

This datetimes can be handled very well by `bokeh`. To profit from the default formatting use `x_axis_type='datetime'` in the definition of your `figure`. The formatter is set to `%H:%M` to show only hours and minutes.

The sultion below uses StringIO to load the data. This section can be removed, when you use the path to your CSV-file.

The bokeh figure itself gets two lines in blue and red (red is the mean).

### Code

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

# here was a typo in your example data with the timestamp 1/28/2022 18.22 
data = """Time  Event   Speed
1/30/2022 00:00     Speeding    50
1/30/2022 17:23     Speeding    50
1/28/2022 18:22     Speeding    20
1/27/2022 22:00     Speeding    30
1/26/2022 23:23     Speeding    40
1/27/2022 22:00     Stopping    10
1/26/2022 23:23     Stopping    10"""

# data handling with pandas
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').dt.time

grouped_by_time = df.groupby('Time')[['Speed']].mean()

source = ColumnDataSource(grouped_by_time)
p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', width=300, height=300)
p.line(x='Time', y='Speed', line_width=2, source=source)
p.title.text = 'Average Speed For Days'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Average Speed'
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Dates'

p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {0: '0h', 24*60*60*1000: '24h'} # this ovverrides hard  by hand -- 24 hours in milliseconds
TOOLTIP = [("Time", "@Time{%H:%M}"),
            ("Average Speed", "@Speed")]
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=TOOLTIP, formatters={"@Time": "datetime"}, mode='vline'))

show(p)
```

### Result

[image: simple line plot over time]

### Further reading

- See the section in the first steps guide about [enabling datetime axes](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/first_steps/first_steps_4.html#enabling-datetime-axes).
- Check out thr bokeh [gallary](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html)
- Check out the bokeh [example page](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples.html) and explicit the [datetime axis example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/basic/axes/datetime_axis.html).

Comment: Hi, i have updated my code and edit it above, however, i am trying to plot my x-axis against the time of a day instead of plotting against days. This is because i am trying to see the correlation between the speed of an event, within the time period of a day. So that i can see if for example, in the afternoon, there is more speed than in the morning, etc. Thanks

Comment: I adited my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks its working now, but for the x-axis, its showing 1/01, 4h, 8h, 12h, 16h, 20h, 1/02. How did u make it show hour by hour? Thanks, i have also edited my code to the latest one.

Comment: It looks like your data has more elements than mine. I used a hard `p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {0: '0h', 24*60*60*1000: '24h'}`. This overrides only the two labels. If you move the visible area, you will see, that the old format is used somewhere else.

Comment: Its correct now, thanks alot for your help. Also may i ask what this 24*60*60*1000: does in the code?

Comment: Would you please mark this answer as accepted. FYI: This 24*60*60*1000 is 24 hours in milliseconds. Thats is the position of the label.